# Neutrino emission rate of neutron stars?

Tags: neutrinos, neutron-stars

I often hear that neutron stars emit 30-40% of their energy as neutrinos.
But how many neutrinos do neutron stars emit per second ?

Comment: This generally depends on how old the neutron star is.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm looking for some ballpark figure.

Comment: I think that figure may refer to the initial supernova that produces the neutron star.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/280586/123208 Also see this answer on our sister site: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/33326/16685 The answers to those questions don't directly answer *your* question, but I think you'll find them interesting.

Comment: https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.astro.42.053102.134013